# GET request works in browser but not in POSTMAN - Cloudfare denies it

Tags: rest, postman

1. I am trying to access the following API and this is the behavior
   API = https://api.btcxindia.com/ticker/

While accessing this API from Postman , I get the output. However, if I leave my postman open and test after say 10 minutes - Getting output error

```
Error : <!DOCTYPE HTML> <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <title>Just a moment...</title>
        <style type="text/css">
    html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    body {background-color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 100%;}
    h1 {font-size: 1.5em; color: #404040; text-align: center;}
    p {font-size: 1em; color: #404040; text-align: center; margin: 10px 0 0 0;}
    #spinner {margin: 0 auto 30px auto; display: block;}
    .attribution {margin-top: 20px;}
    @-webkit-keyframes bubbles { 33%: { -webkit-transform: translateY(10px); transform: translateY(10px); } 66% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-10px); transform: translateY(-10px); } 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); transform: translateY(0); } }
    @keyframes bubbles { 33%: { -webkit-transform: translateY(10px); transform: translateY(10px); } 66% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px); transform: translateY(-10px); } 100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(0); transform: translateY(0); } }
    .bubbles { background-color: #404040; width:15px; height: 15px; margin:2px; border-radius:100%; -webkit-animation:bubbles 0.6s 0.07s infinite ease-in-out; animation:bubbles 0.6s 0.07s infinite ease-in-out; -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both; animation-fill-mode:both; display:inline-block; }   </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">   //
            <![CDATA[   (function(){
    var a = function() {try{return !!window.addEventListener} catch(e) {return !1} },
    b = function(b, c) {a() ? document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", b, c) : document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", b)};
    b(function(){
      var a = document.getElementById('cf-content');a.style.display = 'block';
      setTimeout(function(){
        var s,t,o,p,b,r,e,a,k,i,n,g,f, zHvFeWz={"vFQLFVZTSM":+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))};
        t = document.createElement('div');
        t.innerHTML="<a href='/'>x</a>";
        t = t.firstChild.href;r = t.match(/https?:\/\//)[0];
        t = t.substr(r.length); t = t.substr(0,t.length-1);
        a = document.getElementById('jschl-answer');
        f = document.getElementById('challenge-form');
        ;zHvFeWz.vFQLFVZTSM+=+((+!![]+[])+(+!![]));zHvFeWz.vFQLFVZTSM-=+((!+[]+!![]+[])+(+!![]));zHvFeWz.vFQLFVZTSM*=+((!+[]+!![]+[])+(+!![]));zHvFeWz.vFQLFVZTSM+=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!![]));zHvFeWz.vFQLFVZTSM*=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+[]));zHvFeWz.vFQLFVZTSM*=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!![]));zHvFeWz.vFQLFVZTSM+=+((+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]));zHvFeWz.vFQLFVZTSM+=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]));a.value
= parseInt(zHvFeWz.vFQLFVZTSM, 10) + t.length; '; 121'
        f.action += location.hash;
        f.submit();
      }, 4000);
    }, false);   })();   //]]>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="20">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle">
                    <div class="cf-browser-verification cf-im-under-attack">
                        <noscript>
                            <h1 data-translate="turn_on_js" style="color:#bd2426;">Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</h1>
                        </noscript>
                        <div id="cf-content" style="display:none">
                            <div>
                                <div class="bubbles"></div>
                                <div class="bubbles"></div>
                                <div class="bubbles"></div>
                            </div>
                            <h1>
                                <span data-translate="checking_browser">Checking your browser before accessing</span> btcxindia.com.
                            </h1>
                            <p data-translate="process_is_automatic">This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.</p>
                            <p data-translate="allow_5_secs">Please allow up to 5 seconds&hellip;</p>
                        </div>
                        <form id="challenge-form" action="/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl" method="get">
                            <input type="hidden" name="jschl_vc" value="dbc7ac6d545de8521a2a3f24574a78a4"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="1516515065.895-rdlkMQJ0RT"/>
                            <input type="hidden" id="jschl-answer" name="jschl_answer"/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="attribution">
                        <a href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=iuam" target="_blank" style="font-size: 12px;">DDoS protection by Cloudflare</a>
                        <br>
            Ray ID: 3e081d20db788866

                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body> </html>
```

2. However, if the same API when tested from Browser this doesn't fail even if I try multiple times.

**EDIT-1**
Thank you for the comments. I am trying to provide more details. Please find the attached picture from DEV tools
[image]

**STEP 1**: Executing the request in POSTMAN . Please find the result

**Following were the auto populated header details I could find**

```
alternate-protocol →443:spdy/3.1
cache-control →no-store, no-cache
cf-ray →3e19a7fc98652f11-DEL
content-encoding →gzip
content-type →application/json
date →Tue, 23 Jan 2018 09:16:48 GMT
expect-ct →max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
expires →0
pragma →no-cache
server →cloudflare
status →200
strict-transport-security →max-age=31536000
vary →Accept-Encoding
```

**Cookie Details**
[image]

[image]

**STEP 2 : After 5 minutes, I am just clicking send on Postman - I get the following the error**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <title>Just a moment...</title>
        <style type="text/css">
    html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    body {background-color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 100%;}
    h1 {font-size: 1.5em; color: #404040; text-align: center;}
    p {font-size: 1em; color: #404040; text-align: center; margin: 10px 0 0 0;}
    #spinner {margin: 0 auto 30px auto; display: block;}
    .attribution {margin-top: 20px;}
    @-webkit-keyframes bubbles { 33%: { -webkit-transform: translateY(10px); transform: translateY(10px); } 66% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-10px); transform: translateY(-10px); } 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); transform: translateY(0); } }
    @keyframes bubbles { 33%: { -webkit-transform: translateY(10px); transform: translateY(10px); } 66% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px); transform: translateY(-10px); } 100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(0); transform: translateY(0); } }
    .bubbles { background-color: #404040; width:15px; height: 15px; margin:2px; border-radius:100%; -webkit-animation:bubbles 0.6s 0.07s infinite ease-in-out; animation:bubbles 0.6s 0.07s infinite ease-in-out; -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both; animation-fill-mode:both; display:inline-block; }   </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">   //
            <![CDATA[   (function(){
    var a = function() {try{return !!window.addEventListener} catch(e) {return !1} },
    b = function(b, c) {a() ? document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", b, c) : document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", b)};
    b(function(){
      var a = document.getElementById('cf-content');a.style.display = 'block';
      setTimeout(function(){
        var s,t,o,p,b,r,e,a,k,i,n,g,f, gabJCII={"Hoov":+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]))};
        t = document.createElement('div');
        t.innerHTML="<a href='/'>x</a>";
        t = t.firstChild.href;r = t.match(/https?:\/\//)[0];
        t = t.substr(r.length); t = t.substr(0,t.length-1);
        a = document.getElementById('jschl-answer');
        f = document.getElementById('challenge-form');
        ;gabJCII.Hoov-=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]));a.value = parseInt(gabJCII.Hoov, 10) + t.length; '; 121'
        f.action += location.hash;
        f.submit();
      }, 4000);
    }, false);   })();   //]]>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="20">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle">
                    <div class="cf-browser-verification cf-im-under-attack">
                        <noscript>
                            <h1 data-translate="turn_on_js" style="color:#bd2426;">Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</h1>
                        </noscript>
                        <div id="cf-content" style="display:none">
                            <div>
                                <div class="bubbles"></div>
                                <div class="bubbles"></div>
                                <div class="bubbles"></div>
                            </div>
                            <h1>
                                <span data-translate="checking_browser">Checking your browser before accessing</span> btcxindia.com.
                            </h1>
                            <p data-translate="process_is_automatic">This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.</p>
                            <p data-translate="allow_5_secs">Please allow up to 5 seconds&hellip;</p>
                        </div>
                        <form id="challenge-form" action="/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl" method="get">
                            <input type="hidden" name="jschl_vc" value="f4e119ff9275afc0a1dd291cd3ecf994"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="1516699334.127-JXvj0i+E1V"/>
                            <input type="hidden" id="jschl-answer" name="jschl_answer"/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="attribution">
                        <a href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=iuam" target="_blank" style="font-size: 12px;">DDoS protection by Cloudflare</a>
                        <br>
            Ray ID: 3e19afdd4f322f11

                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body> </html>
```

Header details

```
cache-control →no-cache
cf-ray →3e19afdd4f322f11-DEL
content-type →text/html; charset=UTF-8
date →Tue, 23 Jan 2018 09:22:10 GMT
expect-ct →max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
server →cloudflare
status →503
x-frame-options →SAMEORIGIN
```

**Cookie details**
[image]

Comment: Cloudflare seems to be fronting the API you are accessing: it's their DDoS protection that makes you see this behavior.

Comment: Is there any way I could by pass this. Also, I am not understanding how the same api when executed from Browser works with no issues

Comment: There is a setting in Postman to automatically follow redirects - not sure if that will help. Is checking something while loading the page in the browser, can you get any more information for the dev tools network tab?

Comment: You could also add any relevant cloudfare site cookies to Postman

Comment: The cloudflare page uses a javascript to redirect to the API output. The browser loads the page, executes the javascript and redirects. You might not even notice, but if you enable the console you should be able to follow the flow. OTOH, Postman retrieves the page, and there's nothing to execute the Javascript, so it stays there.

Comment: Thank you @sal . I have added more details. Could you take a look

Comment: Thank you @DannyDainton I have added more information

Comment: Thanks for the update. Have you tried to contact the API provider? The behavior observed is due to how the API provider has setup their server. Cloudflare is somehow shielding the access with a Javascript redirect. I don't think I can provide any more help on this.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an exact solution for your situation but there is a Chrome extension called the [Interceptor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en) which would allow you to redirect Postman queries via Chrome. It might be a good alternative if you would need to use it often and you do not want to copy manually cookies etc.

> Check if your Postman is able to interact with Interceptor, latest Linux snap v6.7.1 cannot!

Check: [How do I access Chrome's cookies in Postman's Chrome App](https://support.getpostman.com/hc/en-us/articles/203779012-How-do-I-access-Chrome-s-cookies-in-Postman-s-Chrome-App-)
and: [Interceptor extension](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/interceptor_extension/)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem with a URL using Cloudfare API. It worked fine on browser, but gave 503 in postman and even Android Retrofit Calls.
Used a VPN while making calls on Android, worked for me.
Try using a proxy server on Postman.